# Changing value of checkbox with bindings

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsbutton

I have a model with a boolean value and 3 strings. I have a UI that has a checkbox and 3 text fields.

The UI elements are all bound to the values in the model using Interface Builder. I'm also using a method on the model to enable and disable the checkbox dynamically using KVO.

What I'm trying to do is set the value of the checkbox to NSOffState automatically when the checkbox is disabled due to a change in the value of the text fields.

The checkbox calls a method in the model called isComplete to check whether the values are ready but setting the value of the model object there seems to send the program into infinite recursion.

Comment: Have you tried using an NSValueTransformer to take care of the logic?

Comment: Did not. KVO seems to do the trick quite nicely though.